# Paypal Sandbox accounts

Tags: api, paypal, sandbox, payment

I am using Paypal's Adaptive Payments API to transfer funds between one of my sandbox accounts and another of one of my sandbox accounts. The transaction returns "success" but I don't see any change in the balance for any of the sandbox accounts. Is this correct or I am supposed to see how the available balance changes for the accounts.

For example: Account1 and Account2 have an initial balance of 100.00
I use the API to transfer 20.00 from Account1 to Account2
I get "SUCCESS" as the result but when I go to check the accounts, they both have a balance of 100.00

Is this how it is supposed to work ?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't getting back to the returnUrl then it isn't completing. I recommend looking over the [api](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/) again. Also, look around the support community. If all else fails, you can send a message to support group.